# "Clicking" anchor element to navigate to next page VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, click

I'm creating an automation that will go through almost 110 pages with **VBA**. These pages have identical layout. I would need to go from one page to another automatically by "clicking" next button. At the very end of every page, there is a "button" (list anchor) that says "Next page". Problem is that the source code does not contain ID which would make it easy to refer with:

getElementById("id").Click

I open browser. That works fine. and I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim links As Object
Dim link As Object

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set links = ieDoc.Anchors

For Each link In links
If link.innerHTML = "innerHTML" Then
link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next link
```

I have tried almost everything I could find from stackoverflow but nothing worked for my needs.

THis is the source code of the "Next button" that I'm trying to click:

```
<li class="pager-next"><a title="Next page" href="/fi/tyosuhde-  edut/kayttokohdehakupage=1&amp;service_type=lunch&amp;keywords=&amp;city=&amp;service=&amp;service_areas=&amp;payment_method=&amp;municipality=&amp;service_coupon_code=&amp;items_per_page=50">seuraava ›</a></li>
```

I quess the problem is that the ClassName is in "li" and not in "a"?

Could some help me??

**EDIT**

Found a workaround!!:

```
Set pages = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")


For Each page In pages
    If (page.getAttribute("title") = "Siirry seuraavalle sivulle") Then
    page.Click
    End If
Next page
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to keep reseting the html document with each refresh.

After a refresh try

```
ieApp.document.querySelector("a[title=""Next page""]").Click
```

---

CSS Selector

[image: Selector]

More info about CSS Selectors: [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

---

**EDIT:**

In your case the actual HTML selector is

```
appIE.doc.querySelector("a[title = ""Siirry seuraavalle sivulle""]").Click
```

Note there is no space after the `"a"` and you will need to leave enough time between clicks to allow the new page to load.

Comment: @SIM I am still trying to learn off your answers. Any further good CSS resources? I read the prior ones you kindly gave.

Comment: Try the two sites as well. [This one](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/) is legendary and consider taking a look at [this site](http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-CSS3_selectors.html) too.

Comment: I get an error: "Compile error. Expected: list separator on )" before I even run the program. Error is pointed to first part of title name: "Next".

Comment: I forgot to double the "" inside . Try the edit. Apologies.

Comment: It resolves that problem, but it is still not working.

Comment: I actually found a workaround with a similar idea that works for my setup. Still don't know why your wont work for me!

Comment: Does the above not work for you? It works for me. What happened?

Comment: Actually now it does. I restarted excel and vb and it worked fine. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Why you needed to double the quote inside for that expression to work @QHarr? Ain't it what you tried in the first place `ieApp.document.querySelector("a[title='Next page']").Click`?